# Аббревиатура в словарях

Tags: этимология, лексикография

Здравствуйте!
В этимологических словарях присутствует аббревиатура др.-инд. при анализе происхождени слов. Какой именно язык обозначает эта аббревиатура?
Если это древне-индийский, то какой именно? Может ли это быть древне-индоевропейский?

Comment: @abgelicakhan, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Аббревиатура др.-инд обозначает "древнеиндийский" - язык древних ариев:

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%8

Comment: Людмила, у вас опять ссылка битая.

Answer (score 0):

Это надо смотреть в обозначениях самого словаря.
Но ничего кроме "индийский" в голову не приходит. Другое дело, что термин "древнеиндийский (язык)" сам по себе вызывает вопросы.
Я продолжу, когда разберусь с ссылкой у Людмилы.

Ага... Судя по всему вот эта ссылка.
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA

Понятно, здесь понятие "древнеиндийский" означает группу близкородственных языков древнеарийского периода, не разделяя ведический и санскрит. Подробности -  по ссылке.